# Making this update query any better

Tags: sql

I am trying to update some rows with a different id, currently I am using multiple queries to do this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE base_resources
    SET value = value + ?
    WHERE resource_id = 1
    AND base_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($update_ore, $_SESSION['baseid']));

$stmt = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE base_resources
    SET value = value + ?
    WHERE resource_id = 2
    AND base_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($update_wool, $_SESSION['baseid']));
```

It must be a better way to do this? It doesn't seem any good at all, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepared Statements can be reused...

```
    $ore = 1;
    $wool = 2;

    $stmt = $db->prepare(" 
                   UPDATE base_resources
                  SET value = value + ? 
                  WHERE resource_id = ? 
                  AND base_id = ?"); 

    $stmt->execute(array($update_ore, $ore, $_SESSION['baseid'])); 

    $stmt->execute(array($update_wool, $wool, $_SESSION['baseid']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you parameterise the id as well. That way you can make it a bit more generic.